# PCIe DIY protocol analyzer / packet spy / monitor - project

Tags: protocol, pcie, monitor

I'm interested in making a device that I can plug into a PCIe slot that can capture PCIe protocol packets.
Along the same lines find a low cost solution so a hobbyist can make their own PCIe interface devices.

For now would start out with a x1 or x4 and work up to an x8 lane device.
(With a x1 lane monitor would it still see x8 packets?)
Is there a low costs solution for this, some DIY logic analyzer that can be tapped into to the PCIe bus?

There are commercial solutions for this but they are somewhere in the $10,000 to $40,000'ish range for a x8 or x16 system.
I'm assuming that they are either terribly complex, and, or to stay in business, to be profitable, they need to be in this price range for the relatively small market they probably have.

In perspective though, I can go to the electronics store and buy a card (network or USB adapter, cheap sound card, etc.) that has a PCIe x8 controller that costs just ~$50.

There has to be a solution where I can buy a PCIe controller chip, and, or one of these said product boards and hack/repurpose it for a protocol analyzer/packet spy/monitor system. In particular if any of these controllers (if "smart") can be reprogrammed/flashed.

Maybe an existing FPGA prototype board can be used for this? They might be in the $1,500 to $5000 range, but at least that's getting closer to a hobbyist budget.

From a ground up DIY solution I see some kind of circuit that takes a PCIe prototype board (seen them in the $500 range), has any required minimal bus buffering/interface, hooked up to an FPGA that is programmed to stream the high speed PCIe packets onto onboard buffer RAM, setup so the RAM can be streamed over USB where a second computer (or microcontroller, etc.) can read and store them.
Then yes I'd have to write the user interface software for it as well.

Any suggestions, anyone make their own DIY solution for this already?

Thanks,

Comment: "...so a hobbyist can make their own PCIe interface devices." Aerosmith wrote a song about this sort of thing called "Dream On."

Comment: What is your specific question?

Comment: Its called a logic analyzer

Comment: PCIE buses run in the GHz range. That means pF's and nH make a difference plus transmission line effects, so I think DIY is not an option. Product recommendations are off topic here.

Answer (score 1):

Well I see a 1.0 x4 analyzer for $1500 on eBay and I know I've seen the pcie card versions come up even cheaper.  Seeing as how all cards must be able to fall back to 1.0 I'd think this would meet the requirement for a hobbiest, or at least this would set a cost starting point for you.

Now if you want to do it yourself I would guess an fpga would be the way to go.   I don't remember seeing and pcie cards with both an edge connector and a pcie slot but you can probably get one that has an edge connector and high speed expansion bus and you could make a board to convert that to a pcie connector.

You'll probably want some ram and maybe some SRAM on there as well to store your packet captures.  Then I'd think you have to write some rtl to either make your fpga look like a switch to the rot complex.  Then you monitor and store some traffic in both directions.

Oh and the most useful thing about the analyzer is the triggers so when you spec it out you should think about some trigger and filter logic to add like only capture tlp packets in this address range.

This is a lot of work vs $1500, on the other hand our 3.0 x16 analyzer was $250k so if you need something in that range that's specific to your product it could be worth it.

Answer (score 1):

It's doable, but it's quite a project. Especially if you do your own boards.

You'd have to use an FPGA with two PCIe PHY modules and build a card with a plug on one side and socket on the other that functioned as a PCIe bridge/"switch". That would then be in a position to capture all the traffic.

You wouldn't necessarily have to route it to a second computer; the bridge itself is an endpoint, and you could just interrogate it from software.

If I wanted to reverse-engineer a PCIe driver, I'd not bother with the hardware and hook into the operating system instead.